# (Dis-)Advantages of typing (polutoniko)greek letters?

Tags: input-encodings, greek

As fan of `teubner.sty` and `gfsporson` I've typed a long document with teubner-Glyph-macros >\~W f\ia le Fa\ic dre ktl.` By chance I found that, without changing anything, I can use the Greek letters themselves as input, which happens to be read somewhat easier.

Now, does anyone guess *any* shortcomings, pitfalls ... with the Greek input? I don't want to make anythings worse and I'm still hopeful that I will use LuaLaTeX one day. To give a MWE with the most important packages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{savesym, cmap}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}
\usepackage[math=normal,main=ngerman,greek,]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames,boldLipsian]{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve}\savesymbol{aa}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\restoresymbol{pplj}{breve}\restoresymbol{pplj}{aa}
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\usepackage{calc,soulutf8}\usepackage[nonegthinspace,twothirds]{thinsp}\usepackage[kerning=true,tracking=true,babel=true]{microtype}\DeclareMicrotypeSet{alltext}{encoding={LGR,T1}}\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\makeatletter\let\|=\relax\addto\greek@shorthands{\declare@shorthand{greek}\/}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.08em}\allowhyphens}{}}  % supposed to imitate "| for German language
  \declare@shorthand{greek}{\|}{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{}{}{\kern.08em}\nolinebreak}{}}  % to imitate "| but without allowing for line breaks
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}Περὶ μὲν οὖν ἀ\|θανασίας αὐτῆς ἱκανῶς· περὶ δὲ τῆς ἰδέας αὐτῆς ὧδε λεκτέον· οἷον μέν ἐστι, πάντῃ πάντως θείας εἶναι καὶ μακρᾶς δι\/ηγήσεως, ᾧ δὲ ἔοικεν, ἀνθρωπίνης τε καὶ ἐλάττονος·\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think part of your MWE got cut off: you need a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`, with a little something in between.

Comment: @Thérèse I hope it works now -- I hate long lines, but else it will cut off two thirds of the doc.

Comment: Special case of [characters - Is there any reason to prefer a unicode symbol versus its LaTeX command counterpart? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618009/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-a-unicode-symbol-versus-its-latex-command-counterp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. The character `Σ` is translated into

```
\u8:Σ
```

which is a single macro whose name is five character long, because `Σ` is two byte in UTF-8. This macro, in turn, is translated into

```
\IeC{\textSigma}
```

and, in a typesetting context, it becomes

```
\textSigma
```

The definition of this macro is

```
\LGR-cmd \textSigma \LGR\textSigma
```

which is three tokens, because the last one is a single control sequence; if the current encoding is LGR, which it is after `\greektext` has been given, just `\LGR\textSigma` survives, which, finally, becomes

```
\char"53
```

and, in the LGR encoding, the slot `"53` (decimal 83) contains an uppercase sigma.

Similarly, `Ὦ` becomes

```
\IeC{\ensuregreek{\@tabacckludge ~>\textOmega}}
```

and, in the same way as before, this is the same as typing

```
~>W
```

which, with the ligature mechanism of LGR encoded fonts, prints “Ὦ”.

Thus typing

```
\textsc{SWKRATHS}\quad\>\~W f\ia le Fa\ic dre, po\ic{} d\hg{} ka\ig{} p\oa\/jen? ktl.
```

or

```
\textsc{ΣΩΚΡΑΤΗΣ}\quad  Ὦ φίλε Φαῖδρε, ποῖ δὴ καὶ πόθεν; κτλ.
```

is perfectly equivalent (after `\greektext`, of course, or something that implicitly executes this macro). The latter method is just a bit slower, because some macro expansion is involved; probably a few hundredths of a second for a long document.

Note, though, that `;` will print a Greek semicolon (raised dot) and not a Greek question mark (Latin semicolon).

You need to type `;` (U+037E) for a Greek question mark.

[image]

Comment: Very good! I used the glyph macros because in the teubner.doc it says that it makes a difference whether you write `\'a` or `\aa`. It *does*, if your faith is strong enough. That's why I defined (and overused) `\/` and `\|`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out how differently LaTeX understands ; and ;. The good thing is, I can still use the latin characters, so I write `\textsc{ΣΩΚΡΑΤΗΣ}\quad  Ὦ φίλε Φαῖδρε, ποῖ δὴ καὶ πό\|θεν? κτλ.`